# how i can call the button inside the if statement PHP

Tags: php, html, button, post, if-statement

I am a newbie I am having a little problem on how can i call the button inside my if statement. I am trying to work on a userlog where when you click a button it will output on the user log.

but how can i call the >>
THE VIEW button inside my if statement so that it will `fwrite` inside the userlog.txt.

inside this `if($_POST['submit'] = ")` same goes in the search button and the add edit delete button. did u get my point?

```
<body background="images.jpg">
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'])
{
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br>";
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="mydata4.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Edit/Delete/add">
</FORM>';
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="mydata2.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="View" id="viewbutton">
</FORM>';
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="display_data.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Search">
</FORM>';
}
else
{
die("You must be logged in!");
}


if($_POST['submit'] = ")
{   
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updatefile = "userlogs.txt";
$fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "User: $username click view button";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
fclose($fh);
}   
?>
```

Comment: is this a typo `if($_POST['submit'] = ")`?

Comment: The `if($_POST['submit'] = ")` should be `if($_POST['submit'] == "")` or just `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if(isset($_POST))
```

instead of

```
if($_POST['submit'] = ")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the same **name** to your **submit** buttons ...

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="View" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" />
```

and in your PHP, you can simply use as you mentioned

```
if( $_POST["submit"] == "View" )
...
if( $_POST["submit"] == "Search" )
...
```

one more things is that, you have to use `method="post"` in your `<form>` tag if you want to use `$_POST` in php

```
<form method="post" action="....php">
```

Comment: SIR IT SHOWS AN ERROR OF Undefined index: submit in C:\wamp\www\My\Login\member.php on line 24

Comment: ok, try this `if( isset($_POST["submit"]) && $_POST["submit"] == "View" )`

Comment: no error sir but the code inside the if statement is not working :((

Comment: Is there a way using ONclick on if statement other than that?

Comment: (1) you have to change `<form method="post" ... />` (2) your submit buttons should have a name `<input type="submit" name="submit" ... />` (3) make sure the spelling is correct "View" proper case

Comment: it would be better if you add your **edited codes** at the end of your question

Answer (score 0):

try this... you are doing mistake in your if condition.

```
<body background="images.jpg">
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['username'])
{
echo "Welcome, ".$_SESSION['username']."!<br><a href='logout.php'>Logout</a><br>";
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="mydata4.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Edit/Delete/add">
</FORM>';
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="mydata2.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="View" id="viewbutton">
</FORM>';
echo '<FORM METHOD="LINK" ACTION="display_data.php">
<INPUT TYPE="submit" VALUE="Search" name="submit" id="submit">
</FORM>';
}
else
{
die("You must be logged in!");
}


if($_POST['submit'] == "submit")
{   
$date=date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$updatefile = "userlogs.txt";
$fh = fopen($updatefile, 'a') or die("can't open file");
$stringData = "User: $username click view button";
fwrite($fh, "$stringData".PHP_EOL);
fclose($fh);
}   
?>
```